# How do I get the value of Arrays ArrayOfObjects in Mongodb-java driver

Tags: java, spring-boot, mongodb-java

My Document Looks like below .I need to get the value of Email Systems.Bob and Email Systems.System = Bob .I have tried with the below MongodbQuery but not getting proper results .Any one can suggest how to get the desired results with Mongodb Java driver.
Query:
db.users.find(
{ "Email Systems": { $elemMatch: {$eq: "Atlas"} } } );

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f0890e870e631865877e"), 
    "user" : "testuser", 
    "Email" : "testuser@sample.com", 
    "Batch Systems" : [
        "STAR", 
        "STORY", 
        "ITEMS",    
    ], 
    "Email Systems" : [
        {
            "Bob" : {
                "System" : "Bob", 
                **"result"** : true
            }
        }, 
        {
            "Wild" : {
                "System" : "Wild", 
                "result" : true
            }
        },
        {
            "CRaft" : {
                "System" : "Craft", 
                "result" : false
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: which queries did you try and didnt work?
Do they work directly at DB and you are not getting in java driver?

Comment: I tried both at DB and in java driver but didn't work . Dynamically I need to get the systems value ( Email Systems .Bob)  if it matches with the input get request paramter , follwoing logic will be applied .Can you help me with the java syntax to get the Bob , Craft values

Answer (score 0):

To fetch `Email Systems.Bob` you can use this query:

```
db.users.find({ "Email Systems.Bob": { $exists: true} })
```

To fetch `Email Systems[].{dynamic-key}.System == 'Bob'`.
I don't think it will be possible to pass some kind of regex for dynamic key in the query, AFAIK.

Here you might fetch all documents with field `Email Systems` and filter it in your java code. (not efficient though)

```
db.users.find({ "Email Systems": { $exists: true} })
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply .Can you help me with the Java syntax for db.users.find({ "Email Systems.Bob": { $exists: true} })